# How to construct sql query with bitwise operation using sqlobject ORM in python3?

Tags: python-3.6, sqlobject

I am trying to create a query in python3 using sqlobject mapper. I have a requirement of filtering a custom field based on the output of bitise operation.
Query looks like this:

```
query = sqlobject.AND(query,dl.<table_object>.q.anomalyType & alert_type == alert_type)
```

But when the actual SQL transformation happens, this bitwise & gets converted into "SQL AND", which changes the whole meaning of the query.

Can someone advise the right way to add bitwise operator in the query sqlobject in python3?

Comment: What SQL do you want to get in result? (I'm the current maintainer of SQLObject.)

Comment: I want sql like "Select * from table1 where column1 & 2 = 2 ". Can this be done ?

Comment: Not with [q-magic](http://sqlobject.org/SQLObject.html#q-magic): it always [maps](http://sqlobject.org/_modules/sqlobject/sqlbuilder.html#SQLExpression) `Table.q.x & y` to `x AND y`. Perhaps you can drop to simple strings: `'anomalyType & alert_type == alert_type'` (note apostrophes). May be `SQLConstant('anomalyType & alert_type == alert_type')` or even `SQLConstant('anomalyType & alert_type') == alert_type`

Comment: SQLConstant did the trick. Thanks @phd for help!

Answer (score 2):

SQLConstant does the trick. Working sql query looks like this:

```
query = sqlobject.AND(query, sqlbuilder.SQLConstant(f'anomalyType & {alert_type}') == alert_type)
```

Thanks for the help @phd.